# Install.ps1 or Web.config.transform - which happens first?

Tags: xml, powershell, web-config, installation, nuget

So, I'm finally *really* needing to do something with Web.config that isn't supported by NuGet's Web.config.transform system.

And after spending 2 hours searching the docs, I realized that there's no word on whether Install.ps1 happens before or after Web.config.transform gets applied.

I used to define a Web.config.transform file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="resizer" type="ImageResizer.ResizerSection"/>
  </configSections>
</configuration>
```

Here's the new one - the `requirePermission="false"` attribute is required to support Medium Trust.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="resizer" type="ImageResizer.ResizerSection" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
</configuration>
```

If I release a new Web.config.transform version, it will crash their ASP.NET project since there will be two section elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="resizer" type="ImageResizer.ResizerSection" />
    <section name="resizer" type="ImageResizer.ResizerSection" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
</configuration>
```

If Install.ps1 happens **before** Web.config.transform, I can just delete all matches to `configuration/configSections/section[@name='resizer']`. If it happens **after**, then I need to select one of the duplicates to remove.

This is a pretty easy problem to solve, but hasn't yet been answered on an internet forum, and by posting it I'm hoping to make the next Nuggetter's life easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just read through NuGet code and install.ps1 happens **after** Web.config.transform.

In NuGet's code below, Web.config.transform is called in the ExtractPackageFilesToProject while installs.ps1 is called in the last event OnPackagageReferenceAdded :

```
    protected void AddPackageReferenceToProject(IPackage package)
    {
        PackageOperationEventArgs args = CreateOperation(package);
        OnPackageReferenceAdding(args);

        if (args.Cancel)
        {
            return;
        }

        ExtractPackageFilesToProject(package);

        Logger.Log(MessageLevel.Info, NuGetResources.Log_SuccessfullyAddedPackageReference, package.GetFullName(), Project.ProjectName);
        OnPackageReferenceAdded(args);
    }


    private void OnPackageReferenceAdded(object sender, PackageOperationEventArgs e)
    {
        Project project = FindProjectFromFileSystem(e.FileSystem);
        Debug.Assert(project != null);
        _providerServices.ScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript(e.InstallPath, PowerShellScripts.Install, e.Package, project, this);
    }
```